# C Storage-class differences?

Tags: c, memory

What is the difference between a variable declared as an `auto` and `static`?
What is the difference in allocation of memory in `auto` and `static` variable?
Why do we use `static` with array of pointers and what is its significance?

Comment: If you've been told to always declare arrays of pointers as static, that's just wrong.  It may be appropriate in a specific situation, however, but not because of the type stored in the array.

Answer (score 7):

**AUTO (default)**, **Static**, **Extern** & **Register** are the 4 modifiers for a variable in C.

---

- **`auto` :** The default storage-class for a C variable. (i.e. no need to explicitly specify `auto`).
- **[`static`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/External_variable#Scope.2C_lifetime_and_the_static_keyword) :** Changes the lifetime of the variable. (retains the scope, no
  change).

This means, during runtime, the OS does **NOT** of delete the variable from memory once the function( containing the variable exits) and initialise the variable every time the function is called.

Rather the static variable is initialised ONLY the first time the function (containing it is called). Then it continues to reside in the memory until the program terminates.
in other words **STATIC** effectively makes a variable GLOBAL in memory, but with only LOCAL access.

Where your statics are stored depends on if they are 0 initialized or not.

- 0 initialized static data goes in .BSS (Block Started by Symbol),
- non 0 initialized data goes in .DATA

One must note that, though static-variables are always in the memory, they can only be accessed ONLY from the local scope (function they are defined in).

- **`extern` :** Used to signal to the compiler that the extern-definition is simply a placeholder, and the actual definition is somewhere else. Declaring a variable as extern will result in your program not reserving any memory for the variable in the scope that it was declared. It is also common to find function prototypes declared as extern.
- **`register` :** Signals the compiler to Preferrably used a CPU-register (and not RAM) to store this variable.
  Used to improve performance, when repeated access to the variable is made (for ex: loop counter variables).

Comment: +1, but.. "Static: For globals, indicates internal linkage. For function-scope variables, indicates they persist across function calls.", "Extern: Indicates the declaration is only a declaration and not a definition.", "Register: ... Is 99.999% obsolete."

Comment: Okay, you've now screwed it up with an edit.  Function-scope statics are not stored on the heap.

Comment: @ROGER U sure?? coz i seem to remember reading about it. PLus since the stack is purged once the function returns, how do U explain the static variables retain their value then?? plz explain...

Comment: I am sure.  There is more than just the stack and the heap; they are stored elsewhere.  In fact, C makes it really easy by only allowing constant expressions for initialization, and initializes them at startup (even though you can't access them until inside the corresponding function).

Comment: Function scope static variables *can* be accessed outside of the scope they're declared in, but such access must obviously be through a pointer.

Answer (score 2):

I'll assume if you're talking about `auto` variables you probably mean local variables in a function. `auto` is the default, it means the variable is allocated on the stack when the function is called and deallocated when the function returns. `static` means the variable is allocated once the first time the function is called, and stays allocated for the rest of the program. This means:

```
int foo() {
    static int x = 0;
    return x++;
}

printf("%d\n", foo()); // Outputs 0
printf("%d\n", foo()); // Outputs 1
printf("%d\n", foo()); // Outputs 2
```

Comment: Probably the following should also be mentioned: `auto` variables can only be declared inside functions, while `static` variables can also be declared outside functions. In fact, top-level variables always behave like `static`, while function-local variables behave like `auto` by default.

Comment: @stakx: Global variables do not behave as if they were declared static by default, and static for them means something different from function-scope statics.

Comment: @stakx: static variables declared outside a function are invisible outside the translation unit they are defined in - unlike an non-static (global, extern) variable.  But in terms of duration, you are correct; both static and global variables have a lifetime of the duration of the program.

Comment: @Jonathan Leffler: You are correct. I should have been more specific, variable lifetime is what I meant.