# What is the relation between C storage-class and C++ destructor

Tags: c++, c

I am very new to C/C++ programming.

- Storage class in `C` signifies the visibility and **life cycle** of a variable.
- In `C++`, Constructor and Destructor are used to initialize & release-resources the object occupied.

Yes, constructor helps reducing much of repetitive code but destructors are used to release and/or free resources (once an object goes out of scope).

Are these concepts coupled in some way in their implementation?

Comment: Although `Storage`-type may be called "Storage class" in C, that has absolutely nothing to do with C++'s "class" concept.

Comment: @Top-Master I'm not asking from an OOP perspective. Do they work in a similar way? or is there a fundamental difference between their implementation and what is expected of them from memory management purposes?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [storage classes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2661369/storage-classes)

Comment: _destructors are used to deallocate memory_ This is IMHO confusing things. Destructors _may_ be used to deallocate things in a class but that depends on what the class is doing internally. I would say the opposite: Something is destructed before it's storage is deallocated. Deallocation of storage isn't the subject of the destructor but the subject of the respective "deallocator" (provided by the compiler e.g. for global and local variables or the `delete` for memory allocated with `new`).

Comment: got it. please close the question, I don't want to delete it, as I might want to revisit it someday.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For `C` Storage classes see: https://stackoverflow.com/a/2661411/8740349

Let's not talk about implementions, as each compiler works differently, but if you ask about C++ spec, most keywords mean the same.

Except that:

- `register` keyword was removed since `C++17` (after being deprecated in `C++11`), without [any alternative](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30809775/8740349).
- `auto` means to auto-detect type, like:

```
auto myVariable = myFunction("blablabla (how old are you, in Chinese)");
```

### Is destructor related to storage-class?

No, C++ Class and/or Struct is destructed before it's storage is deallocated.

As mentioned in comments: Handling deallocation of storage isn't the subject of the destructor but the subject of the respective "deallocator" (provided by the compiler e.g. for global and local variables or the `delete` for memory allocated with `new`).

Comment: so if one wants to go that deep to access register level, how would that be done in c++ nowadays?

Comment: @lousycoder see added link (it was never guaranteed that the C++ compiler would listen to what `register` keyword asks).

Comment: @lousycoder To access registers, asm code could be embedded into the C++ code. However, at best, you leave the task of register allocation to the compiler. For the majority of human developers, you can take for granted that the (modern) compiler will do the better job.